# How to Display WCF Web HTTP Service Help Page like asmx in .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#-3.0

How do I Display WCF Web HTTP Service Help Page like asmx in .net framework 3.5

Comment: Type its urt - ex: http://myserver.com/MyServive.svc

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact page available but you can use WCF utitlity available with Visual Studio 2010.

Use WCFTestClient.

1. Open Visual Studio 2010 command prompt
2. Type WcfTestClient ( It open window)
3. Add Service option
4. Add url like http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex
   you can replace with your hosted service.

Hope this help.

Comment: i get the following error
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Answer (score 0):

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/enabling-help-page-for-rest-service-in-wcf-4-0/

*(I'm literally paraphrasing these links)*

1. Add a description attribute to method, and probably `WebGet` as well, like:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate="/template1", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
   [Description("Description for GET /template1")]
   SyndicationFeedFormatter GetTemplate1();
   ```
2. Expose the endpoint via `web.config`...

   ```
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehavior">
         <webHttp enableHelp="true"/>
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
   <!-- ... -->
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RESTWebServiceBehavior" name="RESTWebService">      <endpoint address="" kind="webHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior" contract="IHello" />

         <!-- ... -->
      </service>
   </services>
   ```
3. ...or in code

   ```
   using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Customers")))
   {
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICustomerCollection), new WebHttpBinding(), "");             
      host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { EnableHelp = true });
      // ...
   }
   ```